# Use asp.net tag to set css class

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I try to set the CSS class of each row dynamically for a HTML table, I found a blog with info how to do it but it doesn't seem to work for me.

```
    <% foreach (var item in Model){%>
    <tr class= "<% Model.GetRowClass(item, "alt", "reg");%>">
```

`Model.GetRowClass` returns a string with the style name, when I run it however no style is applied.

Comment: what class is being applied, and what does your stylesheet look like? The problem is not necessarily in your ASP.

Comment: what does the html for the <tr> look like after the page has rendered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `<%= %>` instead of `<% %>`.  Try this:

```
<% foreach (var item in Model){%>
<tr class='<%= Model.GetRowClass(item, "alt", "reg") %>'>
<% } %>
```